# Kali Linux doesn't detect headphones in audio output list

Tags: kali-linux, audio, pulseaudio

Since I set up my own Kali Linux system, I have a problem. After booting into Kali, it doesn't detect my plugged headphones (normal jack input) and I don't hear anything. I went to settings -> audio and I just didn't see my headphones on the output devices list. It turned out that after executing `pulseaudio -k` in terminal or bash file, it magically fixes itself and everything works properly - my headphones appear on the list and system automaticly switches to them as an output device. But, it works only until next reboot - then I have to do it again and again. And everything would be fine, but of course I'm a lazy human being and I don't want to input the command every time I boot into Kali. Does anyone knows what's going on and how to fix this once and for all? Thanks in advance.